# how to set multiple dictionary on array on my plist file?

Tags: ios

I am creating one simple suitable view with one button.
When button pressed new view spend and one user contact list display.
In this view two field User Name and User Address are placed.

Now my question is when I pressed Save button of fill my text field the content save in array of dictionary form and display the name of person on my table view.

But when I again fill the data for new user and save it then my new dictionary overwrite on my old dictionary.

Please help me i want to require every dictionary for each person.

## The code is

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sample.plist"];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) {
    NSString *sourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"plist"];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:plistPath error:nil];
}

NSLog(@"%@",plistPath);

NSString *personName = self.nameField.text;
NSString *personAddress = self.addressField.text;
NSString *nameKay = @"name";
NSString *AddressKey = @"address";

NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:personName,personAddress, nil];
NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: nameKay, AddressKey, nil];

NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];


[self.plistContainer addObjectsFromArray:dict];
NSLog(@"%@", self.plistContainer);

[self.plistContainer writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: nil];
```

## Image Is

[image]

## App Image is

[image]

Comment: One problem is that you are passing dict, an NSDictionary, to addObjectsFromArray:, which expects an NSArray. Perhaps you want to use addObject: instead?

Comment: That i did but now working same thing happening

Comment: Please update your question to reflect your latest code. Also, it might help to include the NSLog output.

Comment: I have one table view plus button ,pressed on button new view open with two text field. When fill both field and pressed save button data saved in dictionary in to array and that array saved on plist file.Now i fill again new field and press saved the problem is it overwrite on my old dictionary.I want required all dictionary on my plist file.